# Disable color change when clicking on a ListBoxItem

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I use the following style to disable highlighting selected ListBoxItem:

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Style.Resources>
        <!--SelectedItem with focus-->
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
        <!--SelectedItem without focus-->
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

This works, but however when I click on a ListBoxItem, the Item gets first white. How can I disable too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following to your style, if you don't want selection I'd use an ItemsControl instead of a ListBox.

```
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Style.Resources>
            <!--SelectedItem with focus-->
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
            <!--SelectedItem without focus-->
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
        </Style.Resources>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Thanks but I get this error: Property IsSelected is not available in FrameworkElement.

Comment: I didn't encounter that error, I updated the post and added the full style I used. Check the TargetType="ListBoxItem".